# Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(\ln{\frac{1}{x}})^{a}}{(1-x)^{2}} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(\ln{\frac{1}{x}})^{a}}{(1-x)^{2}} dx  $$

What I've got after the substitution $\ln{\frac{1}{x}} = t  $ :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \frac{t^{a}}{(1-e^{-t})^{2}} dt  $$

This should be solved with the Gamma function somehow.

Comment: That's a good approach, because if $a=0$ then the integral is easily solved by substituting $u=1-e^{-t}$ and if $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ then you can differentiate the integrand with respect to $a$ to obtain a recursive relation. Then you solved for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$.

Comment: I feel that we can use Laplace transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is infinite if $a\le 1$. This is because
$$ \frac{t^a}{(1-e^{-t})^2} \approx t^{a-2} \quad (t\to 0)$$
which is not locally integrable in dimension 1.

For $a> 1$,  the geometric series formula $\frac1{(1-\lambda)^2} = \sum_1^\infty k\lambda^{k-1} $(and Fubini's theorem) gives
$$I(a) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\int_0^\infty e^{-kt}t^a dt =\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-a}\int_0^\infty e^{-\tau}\tau^a d\tau = a!\zeta(a).$$

Here, $a!:=\Gamma(a+1)$ and $\zeta$ is the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). This formula seems numerically correct for $a=2$, giving the value $$I(2) = \frac{\pi^2}3 = 3.289868133696452872944830333292050378437899802413596875471\dots$$ (compare [a](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20zeta(2)) with [b](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%200%20to%20infinity%20of%20(e%5E(-t)%20t%5E2)%2F(1-e%5E(-t))%5E2%20dt))

Comment: Just write it as $\pi^2/3$.